# CString to const char * _Source in function strcpy_s

Tags: visual-c++

I have code:

```
char buff[50000];
CString params = "sss" ;
strcpy_s(buff,params);
```

Why `strcpy_s` accepts second param that is `CString`? According to my understanding second param should be of type `const char * _Source`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CString` has a [LPCTSTR conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569(v=vs.60).aspx). The compiler calls this to convert your `CString` to the required `const char *`. So what the compiler does is:

```
strcpy_s(buff, (const char*)params);
```

which is equivalent to

```
strcpy_s(buff, (LPCTSTR)params);
```

which is like

```
strcpy_s(buff, params.operator LPCTSTR());
```

This only works if you are not compiling for Unicode. On Unicode `LPCTSTR` is not `const char *` but `const WCHAR *`, so this would not work.